# sending data from python to php,and getting back json data from php to python

Tags: php, python, json

This is my first question here,as i have recently joined the site,and i really need for help in this.
What i am trying to do is send data from python to php,and then,in php,i am connecting to a database,where i am testing a value,and then i will send back the data to python via a json created in php.
So the code i am using is:
**Python side:**

```
import requests
import  json
getdata = {'cpu': '1324324', 'tempvalue': '34543543'}
resp = requests.post("http://localhost/try.php", params=getdata)
r = requests.get('http://localhost/try.php')#.json()
getdata=r.json()
print(getdata['cpu'])
print(getdata['tempvalue'])
```

For this part,the post method is working all right.but the get get method is not working and i keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: Expecting value: line 2 column 2 (char 3)
```

**And the PHP side is**:
I won't right the connecting to database code,cause it is working alright.

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM temp WHERE cpu = '".$value1."'";
$rs=$conn->query($sql);
#$check=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM temp WHERE cpu = '".$value1."'");
if ($rs === TRUE) {
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    if($row_cnt == 1){
        $result["cpu"] = $value1;#$result is predefined in the script.
        $result["tempvalue"] = $value2;

    }}  
else{
    echo "did not find";
    $response["error"] = "error";
    }

json_encode($response);
```

So that is what i am doing.Is there anything wrong in code?Is the python script getting any data back?or should i add something to it?And is the php script right?Am i really sending back json to python?And thank you all.

Comment: Can you please show the complete traceback of the python error? It seems a json parsing error but it is difficult to say from information you give. You could also print the raw response `r`.

Comment: Ok,this is the traceback i am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Documents\Python\send1.py", line 22, in <module>
    get=r.json()
 There are other lines,but nothing special about it
ValueError: Expecting value: line 2 column 2 (char 3)
And when i use the except i get:
Expecting value: line 2 column 2 (char 3)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question,and it was really easy as usual.

What we must do is add the content type of the php file to be json,so that the python script will know what type of data should be read.So the line of code to add in the PHP script is:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

And it must be at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the PHP side.

You are only returning the `$response` array, but your data is actually in the `$result` array.

So when everything is successful, the json response is invalid since there is no `$response` array created.

You need to adjust your PHP code, here is one example:

```
if ($rs === TRUE) {
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    if($row_cnt == 1){
        $result["cpu"] = $value1;#$result is predefined in the script.
        $result["tempvalue"] = $value2;

    }}  
else{
    echo "did not find";
    # $response["error"] = "error";
    $result["error"] = "error";
    }

json_encode($result);
```

You also have some other problems, like you are not using parameterized queries, so your code is subject to SQL injection and you ignore the result of the first query.

Comment: Thank you for you're help,but i am checking my code,and i don't know where result came from in it,i am using response variable and not result.Yesterday the code worked,but today unfortunately it isn't and i don't know why.